# Automatic click on a button after reloading a page

Tags: javascript, button

Basically I have a button which displays a div when pressed.
Inside this div I have actions which can lead to reloading the page.
I want this button that displays my div to be automatically pressed if the page is reloaded. I already tried this :

```
    window.onload =function(){
        document.getElementsByClassName(className).click();
    }
```

But it does not work.
To reload my page I use:

```
    location.reload();
```

Comment: Just put `<script>document.getElementsByClassName(className).click();</script>` before the `</body>`  tag

Comment: Dont forget to actually change className to your desired divs class..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    document.querySelector(".className").click();
});
```